# how to access nth channel of a Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, channel

I know how to access three channels `cv::Mat` using `Vec3b`. But now I have an `n` channel `cv::Mat` and `n` is not constant (to use `cv::Vec<uchar, n>`). How I can access `cv::Mat` channels now?

Comment: @DimChtz 's answer is perfect, you could also use `.toList()` on your Mat and access the elements.

Comment: Use [`cv::Mat::ptr`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a47ead5654d6577e63a3e154b57976a36).

Comment: @RickM. I think you're mixing this up with Java. There's no such thing in the C++ API. The answer you refer to is far from perfect, as it requires the channel count to be hardcoded -- so it totally fails to solve the problem.

Comment: @RickM. Neither is `ToArray()`, check out the docs. You can either [cast it to a `std::vector`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac81c5d8d528e3e8bca51b20c360027f1), or just use the iterators to populate some container. But, IMHO, making a copy is unnecessary in this case. See my answer for an example approach.

Comment: @DanMašek true that, rusty knowledge of opencv in C++, but I get that for the answer to work, you need the number of channels in compile time because of template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `n = 10` and we want to access `4th` channel of pixel `(i, j)`. Here's a simple example:

```
typedef cv::Vec<uchar, 10> Vec10b;

// ....

// Create the mat
cv::Mat_<Vec10b> some_mat;

// Access 4th channel
uchar value = some_mat.at<Vec10b>(i,j)(4); 

// or 
uchar value = some_mat.at<Vec10b>(i,j)[4];
```

Hope this helps you. Notice that you can omit the `typedef` line, I just think it's easier this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't working, Because n is not defined at compile time and when I use n in cv::Vec<uchar, n> it says "expression must have a constant value".

Comment: @ham.a Yes `cv::Vec<uchar, n>` won't work and AFAIK this is impossible in opencv. I believe my answer is the best solution you got (using opencv).

Comment: so I think the only solution is to use std::vector<Mat>.

Comment: Yes, you could use `std::vector<cv::Mat>`.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to handle arbitrary number of channels, you can use [`cv::Mat::ptr`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a47ead5654d6577e63a3e154b57976a36) and some pointer arithmetics.

For example, a simple approach that supports only `CV_8U` data type would be as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

inline uint8_t get_value(cv::Mat const& img, int32_t row, int32_t col, int32_t channel)
{
    CV_DbgAssert(channel < img.channels());
    uint8_t const* pixel_ptr(img.ptr(row, col));
    uint8_t const* value_ptr(pixel_ptr + channel);
    return *value_ptr;
}

void test(uint32_t channel_count)
{
    cv::Mat img(128, 128, CV_8UC(channel_count));
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    for (int32_t i(0); i < img.channels(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ":" << get_value(img, 32, 32, i) << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (uint32_t i(1); i < 10; ++i) {
        test(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```